# How can I be sure my replacement SPI flash chip will work?

Tags: spi, datasheet, flash

I am currently using the [Cypress CX3](https://www.cypress.com/documentation/datasheets/cyusb306x-ez-usb-cx3-mipi-csi-2-superspeed-usb-bridge-controller) MIPI-USB bridge chip which needs an attached SPI FLASH chip. The datasheet recommends the [W25Q32FW](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Winbond%20PDFs/W25Q32FW_Rev_H.pdf) part, which is now obsolete.

I would like to choose a replacement device e.g. [AT25SL321](https://www.adestotech.com/wp-content/uploads/AT25SL321_112.pdf), but it must obviously be compatible.

What features of the SPI chips must be checked to ensure the replacement is compatible? Is it enough to go through the SPI protocol waveforms and check they all match, or is there anything in the layout of the memory which might be a gotcha? Or are they generally all compatible, and this is nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the datasheets.

Or limit to checking the parameters the chip actually needs.

Fortunately Cypress has published a knowledge base article KBA221833 which instructs how to select a compatible SPI flash.

So if used voltage, clock speed and used commands match, the size just needs to be withing some limits to have the right amount of address bytes in the protocol.

Comment: Nice find of the knowledge base article!